# laravel 5.4 - injecting object to a controller from routes

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have some routes like this.

```
Route::prefix('bots')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'BotController@index')->name('bots');
    Route::get('{bot_username}', 'BotController@edit');
    ...
});
```

what I want is in any way Inject a Bot model object to the second route in order to edit it.

so if we go to

```
mydomain.dev/bots/mybotusername
```

it should automatically call a custom method like `findByUsername` that I will define in a `repository` or a if possible in the `bot model` itself, and it will return a bot model object. in this model I should pass the route parameter `bot_username` and find and make an object and return it. so if it IS returning the object we can access the route to edit the object in `BotController@edit` and if returned null we cant access the route and show 404 error. is it possible?

Comment: Use route model binding and type hint the parameter in your controller method.

Comment: thanks. I checked it and it is working but when I use a non-valid bot username it is still returning an object but when I try to get its $bot->bot_username it will return null. I want to trigger a 404 error in this case. where can I do that. is it possible to do it in RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: You'll need to change the eloquent lookup to use the slug username instead of an id. Then 404 should be thrown if model doesn't already exist in db.

Comment: thanks You saved me a lot of time. Got it working.